# Deploying apps to a Google Cloud Engine VM instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm really new to the world of Google Cloud and I couldn't be more confused. I took advantage of the always free tier to get a Google Cloud Engine VM instance and wanted to use it to do some testing for a couple of things I'm developing.

I've managed Linux servers before with VPS instances, but in this specific case I'm very confused how to actually automatically deploy any of my apps to this GCE VM.

My apps are hosted on Github, so I'm trying to make use of Github Actions, unfortunately most options available require me to create Docker images, push them to Google's Container Registry and then deploy them ([like this official one](https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud)).

Unfortunately the documentation is telling me that [I can only run a single image per VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#limitations), which is fair as I think that's a docker limitation.

Here's the problem, I don't have nearly enough knowledge to set up a docker compose or coordinate pushing images to Google Cloud's container registry. I just have no idea how even start learning that.

Is there absolutely no way for me to run a more traditional web server (Nginx hosting API + Front-end) by just using SSH to log into the VM instance and pulling changes from Github?

I've tried using the `ssh` command to log into one of the accounts on the server, but I don't think the port is even open to allow me to do that.

The `gcloud` command doesn't seem to allow me to provide a JSON key for the service accounts to log in either so I'm completely lost on how I could possibly accomplish this.

Any advice on how I could get around these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot help you regarding your CI/CD question. However, you can configure OS Login to access your VM with your service account:

1. -Enable OS Login in project-wide metadata so that it applies to all of the instances in your project:

```
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata enable-oslogin=TRUE
```

2. Generate Service Account Key file:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create --iam-account [ACCOUNT] [FILE].json
```

The [FILE].json file will be downloaded into the path directory where you ran the command.

3. Activate service account:

gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=[FILE].json

4. Adding SSH keys to a user account

   1. Switch to service account

   ```
   gcloud config set account [ACCOUNT]
   ```

   2. Add SSH key

   ```
   gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add --key-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```

   3. Switch back from service account

   ```
   gcloud config set account your@gmail.com
   ```
5. Gather service account uniqueId

```
gcloud iam service-accounts describe [ACCOUNT] --format='value(uniqueId)'
```

You can now ssh into any instance of the project by using a service account:

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa [sa_<uniqueId>]@[INSTANCE_IP]
```

Note that we prefixed the uniqueId with `sa_`

More info: [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access)

Comment: Forgot to mention that you have to assign these roles to the service account: compute.osAdminLogin and compute.iam.serviceAccountUser

Comment: I think I might be confused by how service accounts work. I created a separate one (not the google account I use) and gave it all the permissions needed. Unfortunately if I try running the command to activate it (step 3) I get a "invalid_grant: Invalid JWT" error, and it asks me to login again. Do I have to login with the service account for this to actually work?

Comment: Yeah, when trying to add ssh keys it just tells me the service account does not have any valid credentials :/

Comment: You need to issue the command in step 3 as project owner (your user@gmail.com). You can check which account you are by running: gcloud auth list, and look for the asterisk. You can switch between accounts by running: gcloud config set account [account].

Comment: Sorry, the problem was caused by WSL's clock being out of whack, which happens often. I've gone through all the steps successfully, unfortunately my login fails right at the end with a "Permission denied (publickey)". I've tried this with multiple service accounts but the result seems to be the same every time.

Comment: Is it a problem with the credentials in the id_rsa.pub key? Should the end of the key contain <whoami>@<hostname> or should it be something else?

Comment: You must ensure that you set the active account for the service account in step 4, otherwise you added the ssh key to the project owner (your gmail account) and not the service account. Did you get your uniqueId? If so, you ssh with sa_uniqueId@IP.ADD.RE.SS

Comment: I'm sure I used the right account. I couldn't use your method to get my id as it tells me the API isn't active, however I can see my id from the console so it should be fine. I'm logging in with ssh <path-to-key> sa_<id>@<ip>.

Comment: Aha! I got it. I didn't realise the id wasn't the string, but an int. I think activating the API takes some time so it only now finally worked. As you said, I got the id from that and used it to login and it worked! Thank you so much for your help, I would've never figured it out on my own

Comment: Glad it worked !!!